# Memory leak while playing sounds with java

Tags: java, audio, memory-leaks

This is my code for playing sounds:

```
public class Sound {
    public static void playSound(String path)
    {
      try 
      {
           Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
           AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(path));
           clip.open(inputStream);
           inputStream.close();
           clip.start(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }               
    }
}
```

If I call Sound.playSound("xxx.wav"); many times I see that my ram according to the task manager starts to rise dramatically. How do I clean that up?

Comment: Well, if you _open_ a stream, don't you think you should _close_ it as well? :)

Comment: I would say that you need to close the clip - `clip.close()`

Comment: right my bad Ill close the stream, but how do I close the clip at the right time? how do I know when the sound has ended and how do I refer to a specific clip if I played many at the same time

Comment: 1. There is no `close()` method in `Clip` interface. 2. Did closing the input stream helped ? 3. Do you run it many times at once or one after another?

Comment: 2. no 3. one after another many times

Comment: @Fazovsky Methods inherited from interface javax.sound.sampled.Line: addLineListener, close, getControl, getControls, getLineInfo, isControlSupported, isOpen, open, removeLineListener

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/PlaysoundwithAudioInputStream.htm) might be worth a look. Have deleted my answer as it's not relevant to audio streams.

Comment: OK. Maybe this is normal "Java feature" - it uses memory (to load resources, it doesn't recognize it is the same), but releases it when garbage collector is invoked (from time to time, or explicitly System.gc() ). #justaguess

Comment: @Fazovsky open streams still need to be closed, but it needs to be handled differently for audio (and presumably video) because they have to play to completion before the streams need to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try the close method. From the JavaDOC:

> void close() Closes the line, indicating that any system resources in
>   use by the line can be released. If this operation succeeds, the line
>   is marked closed and a CLOSE event is dispatched to the line's
>   listeners.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have written your Clip (including the loading with the playback) suggests that a SourceDataLine would be more efficient. Loading Clips at the same time as playing them creates a lot of needless latency. A Clip will not start to play until the file loads *completely* into RAM, while a SourceDataLine will commence immediately (as soon as it starts receiving file data).

Clips should be loaded once, via open(). Once opened, the data sits in RAM, ready to go. Clips were designed for multiple plays with the lowest possible latency. But that low latency is only achieved if you separate the load from the play, and are just calling the play on an already loaded Clip.

The build up in memory allocation could be due to the continued reloading of all your Clips into RAM. (Each call will create an additional instance in RAM, and audio files are not cheap.) If you replay a Clip, only load it once and reuse it with multiple start() calls.

Using SourceDataLine is another option. It will not load the entire sound file into RAM, but will stream it from the file location. But be sure and close it when you are done, as unclosed data lines or file streams can be another source of memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as others suggest - use `close()` method on `Clip clip`. Close `inputStream` as well (as you did now).

Other thing is that Java manages memory itself (by JVM - Java Virtual Machine). E.g. objects are cleared where they become obsolete (i.e. out of scope, with no reference). It is different from C++ where you have to allocate and deallocate memory.

But in Java that "deallocation" happens using `Garbage Collector` (there are plenty of references on the web). GC is invoked by JVM and it is hard to tell exactly when.

So what we see here is that Java loads some resources into memory (handles it in an object manner). Each of them use up your system memory. Memory will not be cleared immediately after usage. It will be cleared once JVM invoke GC. It doesn't mean you have memory leak.

**Two hints:**

- JVM invokes GC in case there is low system memory, so you shouldn't be worried about being left with no resources (unless you use lots of resources in the same time).
- you can manually "ask" GC to act using Java code: `System.gc()` but it isn't guaranteed it will do it immediately.

**EDIT:**
To confirm this try to invoke gc manually (System.gc()) and see if it releases memory, but you shouldn't use it in your final solution.